# Session is empty object {} on react but working on postman

Tags: node.js, authentication, session, session-cookies, session-variables

I have session based authentication (the website is for one person so its one-user auth type)
i setted up the backend nodejs with the following:
pacakges used : `cookie-session`, `cors`

```js
const sessionConfig = {
  secret: tokenSecret,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1,
  },
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
};
app.use(session(sessionConfig));

app.use(morgan('dev'));
console.log(NODE_ENV === 'production' ? PRO_URL : LOCAL_URL);
const corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: NODE_ENV === 'production' ? PRO_URL : LOCAL_URL,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(routes);
```

frontend axios:

```js
const API_BASE_URL = 'myURL';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
});

await api.post('protected route') // this leads to 401
```

req.session is empty object on the backend when using the react app to use my apis

when trying to access protected routes I CAN"T on the react app

and the login => access protected route => logout : WORKS FINE ON postman or insomnia

I tried changing cookies settings but that didn't work
the weird things that they work on postman !

am i using anything wrong i stuck with this error since 10 hours i dont know what to learn what to do to fix it

EDIT:
it worth to know how i handle the login

```js
async function login(req, res, next) {
  try {
    if (req.session.isAuth)
      throw new ApiError('الحساب مسجل الدخول مسبقا', StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST);
    const { password } = req.body;
    console.log(password);
    if (password?.toString() !== WEBSITE_PASSWORD)
      throw new ApiError('كلمةالسر غير صحيحة', StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED);
    req.session.isAuth = true;
    return responser(res, StatusCodes.ACCEPTED);
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand the context of what your issue is, when does your backend returns `401` - since that's what you are getting? Post that code

Comment: On the frontend what does your `api.post` call is supposed to do? Just to send cookies and is that what's failing on your backend?